# Upload .txt and keep formating

Tags: php

I have been trying to upload a .txt to my server via a simple php script I made. Everything seems to uploaded correctly, if I open the .txt in Dreamweaver I can see all the formatting is still in tact with spaces and paragraph breaks.

The problem I have is when I try to open that file with PHP and import the contents onto my site. I'm not using an editor right now, just a simple div where the contents are echoed.

I don't have much experience with uploading/downloading using PHP. Am I not using a command to handle the file contents and keep the initial formatting?

In the end I want the user to upload a file, and have PHP read the file and extract certain elements from it based on the number of spaces between paragraph breaks and such.

I was able to actually echo the .txt using URLENCODE() which kept the formatting and made all my spaces +'s. Thats the closes I got, but the original file isn't uploaded in the format so I can't do a count for +'s and select x characters after the last +.

Hmmm, if someone knows of a script already available that can do this or similar to with me just tweaking that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload script is not faulty, you forgot that HTML doesn't respect whitespace. If you want HTML to respect your whitespace in a piece of text wrap it in the `<pre>` tag or through css:

```
white-space: pre;
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML ignores spacing and newlines.
In order to force the browser to process your whitespace, you need to put the text into a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

When you echo text into a div I bet you that the formatting is actually being kept, but HTML tends to make a sequence of whitespaces into a single whitespace when it displays on the web page. Try "View Source" and I bet your formatting is still there. In order to show the formatting properly try echoing the text content into a "pre" tag instead of a div